# XFBML like button disappear after like

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I create some like buton with xfbml. It's working for a week, but yesterday fortuitously stop working. I don't change the code.

The issue:
When I click the like button everything is ok. After I refresh the site, then those like buttons which were clicked they are disappeared.

This is not a css problem, the like div is empty.

The iframe embed is working.

[Test site](http://fb.grtest.hu/wall/index2.php)

Please help!

Comment: I'm having the same problem, fb div doesn't have anything inside

Answer (score 0):

Having same issue only on new blog posts i bring online. Older posts that already have LIKES seems to be unaffected. Just noticed this Monday.